# Массивы в PowerShell.Инициализация, заполнение в цикле

Tags: массивы, powershell

Очень простой вопрос и не могу решить целый вечер.

```
for ($i = 0; $i -lt 5; $i++)
    {
        $BBQ[$i] = $i
    }
$BBQ
```

Почему этот код не работает?
"Не удается индексировать в массив  NULL"

Если добавить вначале `$BBQ = @()`, ничего не  получится.
Работает только если заранее объявить массив, например так:`$BBQ = @(1,3,5,7,4,6)`
А что делать,если неизвестно заранее количество элементов?

Comment: вместо 5 написать $BBQ.count
...

Answer (score 2):

Нашел ответ:)

```
$BBQ = @()
    for ($i = 0; $i -lt 5; $i++)
    {
        $BBQ[$i] += $i
    }
$BBQ
```

Всё дело в фиксированной длине массивов!

Comment: `Index was outside the bounds of the array.` же...

Answer (score 1):

Если после объявления массива `$BBQ = @()`, необходимо добавить элемент, то необходимо воспользоваться командой `+=`.

```
$BBQ = @()
$BBQ += 2 # 2
$BBQ += 7 # 2, 7
$BBQ += 5 # 2, 7, 5
```

Но данный вариант не очень хорошо подходит для больших массивов из-за того что в PowerShell массивы не изменяемые. И при каждом добавлении пересоздаётся весь массив. Для такой задачи подойдёт класс `System.Collections.ArrayList`

```
$BBQ = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
$BBQ.Add(2)
$BBQ.Add(7)
$BBQ.Add(5)
```

Если нужен массив как в вопросе все значения от 0 до 4, то проще всего будет воспользоваться числовым диапазоном.

```
$BBQ = 0..4 # 0, 1, 2, 3, 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете сделать Hashtable, тогда ваш код сработает:

```
$BBQ = @{}
for ($i = 0; $i -lt 5; $i++) {
    $BBQ[$i] = $i
}
$BBQ

Name Value
---- -----
4    4    
3    3    
2    2    
1    1    
0    0
```